# Git reset loses track of moving files

Tags: git

I've got a git repo that looks like this

```
          v master
A <- B <- C <- D
               ^ foo
```

where `master` and `foo` are two branches.
I want to merge `foo` into master, but I want to refactor commit `D` first.
The differences between `C` and `D` are the following:

- A couple of files have minor changes.
- Several files were moved from their old location to a new one in a new directory.
  I'd like to split `D` up into two commits, one with the edits and one with the file moves.
  Normally I'd do this by checking out `D`, doing `git reset C`, and then committing stuff as I see fit.

However, when I do `git reset C`, git seems to completely forget that some of the files were moved renamed. Instead, it thinks that I deleted some files and created some other ones.

How do I help git understand what's going on, so that I can split the edits and file moves?

Here's a complete shell session illustrating the issue:

```
~/src/junk$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in <snip>
~/src/junk$ touch a.txt b.txt c.txt
~/src/junk$ git add a.txt b.txt c.txt 
~/src/junk$ git commit -m "Initial commit."
[main (root-commit) c76830b] Initial commit.
 3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
 create mode 100644 b.txt
 create mode 100644 c.txt
~/src/junk$ mkdir Subdir
~/src/junk$ git mv b.txt c.txt Subdir/
~/src/junk$ echo "This is text." > a.txt
~/src/junk$ git add a.txt 
~/src/junk$ git commit -m "Moved b.txt and c.txt, edited a.txt."
[main 9efc354] Moved b.txt and c.txt, edited a.txt.
 3 files changed, 1 insertion(+)
 rename b.txt => Subdir/b.txt (100%)
 rename c.txt => Subdir/c.txt (100%)
~/src/junk$ git reset HEAD~1
Unstaged changes after reset:
M   a.txt
D   b.txt
D   c.txt
~/src/junk$ git status
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   a.txt
    deleted:    b.txt
    deleted:    c.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    Subdir/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: I think showing us the commands and outputs before/after the reset operation would help a lot understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `git reset --soft`. Can you give it a try and see if the result is what you expect to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default mode of operation of `git reset` is `--mixed` which means that (from `git help reset`):

```
Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated.
```

So, if index is getting adjusted to what it was in the **first** revision (only the original files are there), then when comparing with working tree, b.txt and c.txt are deleted, a couple of new files are untracked in Subdir and a.txt was modified, just what you see in the status report.

What you are probably expecting to see is what `git reset --soft` does. `--mixed` updates where `HEAD` points to and also the index.... `--soft` only moves the pointer but the index is kept **as is**. I think that is what you want, right?

**You can stop reading at this point**. What follows is some additional stuff I had posted previously in the answer but that is not really relevant because the question is all about the reset operation:

As a general rule: **do not care** if git notices that files moved or not. Actually, git **doesn't care** about. That's information that is not tracked **at all**. A movement is *inferred* by git by checking files that are added and deleted between revisions (being one after the other or in ranges, like when merging). If the files' contents look close enough (and this level can be set at will, if I recall correctly) then git will consider that the file was moved..... you might have a situation like this:

```
A <- B <- C ............. <- L <- M ........ <- X
```

And suppose that on B you renamed a file (no content change, to make the example clearer). Then you check with `git diff A L` and see the file as being renamed.... but if the file changes enough between L and X, if you did `git diff L X`, file would be a simple diff with a lot of changes on the same file, but then you try `git diff A X`, you could get **not** a rename but a deletion/creation of the file. It all depends on **how different** the content is between the original file in A and the final file in X.

Comment: Ok. I still do not understand why following `git mv` a call to `git status` tells me that the file was moved, whereas after committing those changes and doing `git reset`, `git status` shows untracked new files and deleted files. Ah, maybe I need to re-add the moved files...

Comment: Hmmm, nope... `git add Subdir/` followed by `git status` still shows `b.txt` and `c.txt` as deleted.

Comment: Sure.... right after resetting (`--mixed`), if you haven't asked git to rm b.txt and c.txt, if you added the new files in Subdir, they would be _new files_ and the original b.txt and c.txt would _still_ be in the index. You can try checking the content of the index after adding with `git ls-files --stage`. You will see that the original files are **still** listed.... and even more, if you asked git to rm b.txt and c.txt **at this point**, then it would report the files as being moved, even though you added/deleted them,... again git just checking contents of stuff that was added/deleted.

Comment: The heart of my confusion is that `git reset --mixed` leaves `b.txt` and `c.txt` deleted but those deletions aren't staged. Thanks :-)